# PHP Access StdClass's within an athor StdClass

Tags: php, stdclass

How to access to  StdClass's element who is within an athor StdClass.

this is what var_dump return:

```
 stdClass Object
(
    [return] => stdClass Object
        (
            [barCode] => 530884HB|4320000007;502241VA|4320000008;
            [code] => 0
            [idAffiliate] => 0
            [idOrder] => 25
            [idProduct] => 320
            [message] => Résérvation effectué avec succés
            [quantity] => 2
        )

)
```

And I want to get the value of the [barCode]??

Comment: `$object->return->barCode`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the property `return` is a public property, you could simply get the `barCode` like this:

`$object->return->barCode`

Example:

```
$object = new StdClass();
$object->return = new StdClass();
$object->return->barCode = '530884HB|4320000007;502241VA|4320000008';
```

`var_dump` of the object:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
  ["return"]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
    ["barCode"]=>
    string(39) "530884HB|4320000007;502241VA|4320000008"
  }
}
```

`print_r` of the object:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [return] => stdClass Object
        (
            [barCode] => 530884HB|4320000007;502241VA|4320000008
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man that is work perfectly